# How does low-intensity aerobic exercise affect the brain?

Tags: exercise, neurology

I have been reading articles claiming that serotonin, endorphins and BDNF are produced during exercise, but they never mention the intensity or duration of exercise for this to happen.

To not make this question too broad, I want to narrow it down to, lets say, a brisk walk which lasts around 30 minutes. So, your pulse increases, but not by as much as a run.

How will this affect the brain? Which chemicals do the body produce that could have an effect on the brain? And, how much?

I am asking because I am always curious about the mechanisms underlying the effects of exercise on the brain and because it's always difficult to find information regarding results of exercise; Googling mostly results in content marketing articles (like [this one for Buffer](https://www.fastcompany.com/3025957/what-happens-to-our-brains-when-we-exercise-and-how-it-makes-us-happier)). Also, I'll as a separate question regarding the effects of high-intensity aerobic exercise.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Alright, I've added more information. I hope it suffices.

Comment: Welcome to this site @Avatrin, good question. Chris already gave most good feedback in the comment above. It is advisable to find and reference to some studies or publications that are reliable and understand (part of) your question. One more request, please change the title into a question such as "How does low-intensity aerobic exercise affect the brain?" or "How is the brain affected during low-intensity exercise?".

Comment: @BobOrtiz Yeah, those are better titles. It's done :)